# Integrate only one variable of a 2D interpolating function

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, interpolation

Lets say I have generated a 2D interpolating function using the code:

```
da = Flatten[Table[{t, tau, N@Sin[2 (t + 3 tau)] Exp[-2 t - tau]}, {t, 0, 2, 2/100}, {tau, 0, 5, 5/100}], 1]
f = Interpolation@da
```

and I want to integrate over one of the variables (I realise that in this case the integral can be done analytically, but I want to integrate an interpolating function from NDSolve which is too complicated to post here...). I can do this using something like:

```
tend = 2;
tauend = 5;
dtau = tauend/100; 
taurange = Range[0, tauend,dtau];
int = Table[NIntegrate[f[t,tau],{t,0,tend}],{tau,taurange}];
intfunc = Interpolation@int;
```

but this seems somewhat inelegant, and also is pretty slow. Is there a better way to approach such a problem?

Comment: `Integrate[f[x, y], x] /. x -> 1`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Integrate[ifn[x], x]` on an `InterpolatingFunction` `ifn` with domain `{x1, x2}` to compute the equivalent of the indefinite integral `Integrate[ifn[t], {t, x1, x}]`:

```
da = Flatten[
   Table[{t, tau, N@Sin[2 (t + 3 tau)] Exp[-2 t - tau]}, {t, 0, 2, 
     2/100}, {tau, 0, 5, 5/100}], 1];
f = Interpolation@da;
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = f["Domain"];

intx = Integrate[f[x, y], x] /. x -> x2;

nintx[y_?NumericQ] := Module[{x}, NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, x1, x2}]];

Plot[nintx[y], {y, y1, y2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[intx, {y, y1, y2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is spot on, I hadn't realised that Interpolating functions could be integrated in this way, thanks!

Comment: Does this work for interpolating functions returned from NDEigenSystem? I have tried it but it doesn't seem to be so have asked it as a question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228352/integrate-over-one-variable-of-a-2d-interpolating-function-returned-from-ndeigen

Comment: @Anthony `NDEigensystem` returns an `InterpolatingFunction` with a domain based on an FEM `ElementMesh` instead of tensor (rectangular) grid.  The mesh is usually made up of a triangulation of the domain.  Breaking it down by coordinates is not natural, since coordinate lines such as $x=x_0,\, a<t<b$, do not correspond to the elements of the mesh.  It is possible to construct an `ElementMesh` of a rectangular domain with rectangular elements, but I doubt `Integrate` will integrate it as above. I haven't tried, though.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do this is to have [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) output the desired integral directly. Let's take your example and convert it into a differential equation:

```
g[t_, tau_] := Sin[2 (t+3 tau)] Exp[-2 t-tau]

base = NDSolveValue[
    {D[u[t, tau], t] == D[g[t, tau], t], u[0, tau] == g[0, tau]},
    u,
    {t, 0, 2},
    {tau, 0, 5}
];
```

A comparison with your `f` function:

```
Row[{
    Plot3D[base[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}, ImageSize->300],
    Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}, ImageSize->300]
}]
```

[image]

Augmenting the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) with an integral:

```
{base, integral} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    D[v[t, tau], t] == u[t, tau], v[0, tau] == 0,
    D[u[t, tau], t] == D[g[t, tau], t], u[0,tau] == g[0, tau]
    },
    {u, v[2, tau]},
    {t, 0, 2},
    {tau, 0, 5}
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002504, Null}

Quite a bit faster than your approach. A comparison with your `intfunc` function:

```
Row[{
    Plot[integral, {tau, 0, 5}, ImageSize->300],
    Plot[intfunc[tau], {tau, 1, 101}, ImageSize->300]
}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

As @MichaelE2 suggest, you could also symbolically integrate the interpolating function. Instead of [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate), I use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative):

```
h = Derivative[-1, 0][f];
Plot[h[2, tau], {tau, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, I was about to post my answer a couple of hours ago when I got called away.  I didn't see your answer until I posted.  Oh well...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't appreciated you could use NDSolve in such a way. As it turns out, your answer inspired me to alter some other code, speeding it up 1000 fold!